# Dreamweaver CS6 Site Setup for Test Site with MAMP and WordPress NIGHTMARE

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, dreamweaver

I have been trying to set-up a test site server on Dreamweaver CS6 IDE (which I hate) to try out the Dynamically-related files theming feature. I have been attempting to do this for hours and looked at more tutorials and blogs than I can remember attempting to set-up a test site so that I can simply try out this feature but nothing seems to work.

**On the Site box I have:**

> Site Name: test site
>   Local Site Folder: users/myname/Sites/wordpress/

**On the Servers I have:**

> Server Name: Apache
>   Connect using: Local/Network
>   Server Folder: users/myname/Sites/wordpress/
>   Web URL: http://localhost:80/wordpress/
>   Advanced:
>   Server Model: PHP MySQL

Yet I am receiving the an Error message:

> Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site
>   definition is not correct for this server

Which makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dreamweaver has an habit of putting that error, but the site would work fine anyway. You have to tell in what particular part you're stuck. Is your wordpress site set up already? Did you successfully perform the Famous 5-Minute Install? http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install

Comment: I managed to get it working by upgrading to MAMP PRO. However I have to admit i am a bit disappointed with the Wordpress theming feature, i was under the impression that this feature would somehow convert PHP syntax into HTML so that it can be easily edited...

Answer (score 4):

"***i was under the impression that this feature would somehow convert PHP syntax into HTML so that it can be easily edited...***"

What in God's name gave you that impression? PHP is server-side scripting; a way for the browser to communicate with the server and database and HTML is a way for the browser to communicate with the client (you) and render things in a form which is usable by humans. There is no "conversion", as they are two universally different languages, each serving unique functions.

In order to "easily edit" PHP, the only solution is to *learn* PHP scripting and syntax.

MAMP's sole purpose is to install an Apache server, PHP, and mySQL on your local computer for a server-side/database framework, such as WordPress, to store information and communicate with. Essentially like creating a mini web-host on your local machine, allowing you to check the functionality of PHP based applications.

Answer (score 0):

These setting are working for me:

1. Open the Dreamweaver Site Setup window
2. Select "Servers"
3. Server Name: localhost
4. Connect Using: Local/Network
5. Server Folder: MAMP/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_directory_name/
6. Web URL: `http://localhost:8888/your_directory_folder/`

For a full explanation: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue and found [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/629061).
The post that explains a bit what we want to hear is post #6 by David_Powers on 01-May-2010 at 05:31.

So to make the problem go away you can go to 'Edit -> Preferences' and disable 'Discover Dynamically-Related Files' while leaving 'Enable Related Files' activated.

Although this fixes the error display I don't quite understand what David_Powers says this function will do and if I actually want it turned on. If someone could help me realize what this option does I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant, but after many tries to figure out the Server not found error, I stumbled across MAMP Preferences on the start up page.

After clicking on Preferences, I noticed that the Document Root was pointing to username/Sites instead of MAMP/htdocs.

[MAMP Preferences > Document Root > browse to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X073.png)

After I set the Document Root folder to htdocs, I finally got Dreamweaver CS6 to display my php file when I clicked the Live button in split screen mode.

None of the other answers I searched mentioned setting MAMP preferences to the Document Root folder. I hope this helps.