# Made custom type for PHP, Dreamweaver doesn't show related files

Tags: php, dreamweaver, custom-type

I've added a custom extension for PHP lets call it .xx, I did it by adding .xx to Extensions.txt and MMDocumentTypes.xml.

Now they are treated and compiled s PHP, but the related files aren't showing when using:
require('somefile.xx');

I tried:
restarting DW
double checked the edits i made are there and right

Environment:
MAC Mavericks
DW CC
MAMP

Comment: IMO: You problem is that your using Dreamweaver ([Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) FTW)

Comment: DW version CC is really fast and different than the previous versions, trust me.

Comment: `.php` on php scripts is purely a convention. PHP couldn't care less what the filename is. if you `require()` or `include()` a file, any `<?php ... ?>` blocks inside that file will be executed. you could embed PHP code into a JPG comment, include the jpg, and the code would run.

Comment: you are right, yet my main issue isn't that the files not being executed, its why DW stopped relating the files.

Comment: @OmarNShamali lol, let me help you. Dreamweaver still takes a few seconds to load and still has that stupid splash screen right. Sublime is **instant**. Just sit there and watch sublime texts home page for about 2 minutes. I'd bet that it will make you at least try it... btw, one of the home page demos actually solves your problem.

Comment: Also, just to be clear. I am actually a big fan of almost all the other Adobe products, and I am proficient in about 80% of the master collection, including Dreamweaver. I actually started learning to code on Dreamweaver. But after I did research on all the other IDEs available, Dreamweaver came dead last in my book.

Comment: @NickJ i've downloaded and tried Sublime, its quick but not smart as DW, i believe its missing the manage sites (very important to me), related files, version control..etc which are in DW.
I'm a big fan of Adobe too, I have 99%% of their products, lol.
anyways, thanks for the try but my issue not solved yet.

Comment: Ok I can except that for now, but I would suggest continuing to try Sublime and installing [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) so you can install the plugins you want (e.g. Git support, themes, more snippets, etc.).

Comment: @NickJ i'll tonight, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer in a kinda different question:

```
Open the Dreamweaver Site Setup window
Select "Servers"
Server Name: localhostConnect Using: Local/Network
Server Folder: MAMP/ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_directory_name/
Web URL: http://localhost:8888/your_directory_folder/
```

[Dreamweaver CS6 Site Setup for Test Site with MAMP and WordPress NIGHTMARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808235/dreamweaver-cs6-site-setup-for-test-site-with-mamp-and-wordpress-nightmare)